# what should be the mysql query to fetch recently added message by a group of users which are stored in the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following table structure

[image]

and i want the result to be

[image]

Here is the query which i tried

```
select * from table where userid IN(201,202,203,204,205)
group by userid
order by messageid desc
```

But i dint get the latest records based on messageid.
I need to write this in a single query as i must use order by clause

Please explain my mistake and provide a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the table to itself using the `max` of the `messageid` if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
select t.messageid, t.userid, t.data
from yourtable t
  join (
    select max(messageid) maxmessageid, userid
    from yourtable
    where userid in (201,202,203,204,205)
    group by userid
    ) t2 on t.userid = t2.userid and t.messageid = t2.maxmessageid
order by t.messageid desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32d4e/2)

---

Edit: Here's an alternative approach using `IN`:

```
select messageid, userid, data
from yourtable
where messageid in (
    select max(messageid) maxmessageid
    from yourtable
    where userid in (201,202,203,204,205)
    group by userid
    ) 
order by messageid desc
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32d4e/3)

Comment: Does this increase query execution time. because we may have some 1000's of records?

Comment: Actually i tried in the same way but later worried about the execution time.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d -- this would definitely increase performance time over a standard query.  However, given your needs, I don't see a quicker solution.  Instead of the `JOIN`, you could consider using `IN` assuming `messageid` is a primary key.  Not sure which would be quicker, but I can post that solution as well.

Comment: Ya JOIN will be quicker as far as i know. Thank alot for making it more simple.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d -- no worries, glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, MAX(messageid) max_messageid
                        FROM yourtable
                        WHERE userid IN (201,202,203,204,205)
                        GROUP BY userid) mx
  ON yourtable.messageid=mx.max_messageid
     AND yourtable.userid=mx.userid
```